# Show different content-related templates for ListView item

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-8, datatemplate

I have this data structure:

```
Post {
       attachments { }, 
       postText
}
```

To display this, i am using ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PostTemplate}"
          Width="Auto"
          Height="Auto" />
```

The problem is, when i am trying to display a list of attachments inside each post.
Every attachment is simply typed link for some typed content (video/audio/image)

```
Attachment {
    type: video,
    url: urlToVideo
}
```

How can i display context-based template for rendering all kind of this content in attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a wpf developer my first answer was to use triggers but according to this article [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/77604041-b991-4f1e-9adb-78c701ac4d9a/) is not an option for windows-8 app. But as you can see there is a way to do that using `DataTemplateSelector`. I assume that you have created one template for one attachment type and you display attachments as some `ItemsControl` so simply fallow this [article](http://www.comyoucom.com/implementing-a-custom-datatemplateselector-in-winrt/).